# How to get Dynamic Data in email newsletter from the website in asp.net c#?

Tags: asp.net, sendmail, sendmessage

I have a newsletter design in which i have to bind data dynamically and send mail to users in asp.net c# through noreply@xyz.com
I tried but getting error of authentication if anyone knows please sort out the problem.

```
 MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
        MailAddress fromMail = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com");
        // Sender e-mail address.
        Msg.From = fromMail;
        // Recipient e-mail address.
        Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("xyz@gmail.com"));
        // Subject of e-mail
        Msg.Subject = "Send Gridivew in EMail";
        Msg.Body += "Please check below data <br/><br/>";
        Msg.Body += GetGridviewData(gvUserInfo);
        Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        string sSmtpServer = "";
        sSmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
        SmtpClient a = new SmtpClient();
        a.Host = sSmtpServer;
        a.EnableSsl = true;
        a.Port = 587;
        a.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        a.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "abc@123");
        a.Send(Msg);
```

Grid View Code

```
 public string GetGridviewData(GridView gv)
{
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter(strBuilder);
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(strWriter);
    gv.RenderControl(htw);
    return strBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: Getting Error "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. "

Comment: @shashank add GetGridviewdata(gvuserinfor) code

Comment: try these two  `a.EnableSsl = false;
                        a.Port = 25;`

Comment: @shreesha new error comes "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. dh9sm6287476pdb.67 - gsmtp"

Comment: check the credentials.are they correct?

Comment: yes the credentials are correct